# Are there matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB = BA \neq I$

Tags: matrices

I've been learning about matrices and the identity matrix $I$.
It says when $AB = BA = I$, then $A$ and $B$ are inverses of one another.
Is it possible for $AB$ to equal $BA$ but not equal $I$?

Comment: Yes, take $A=B$. Or any $A$ and $B=0$.

Comment: Yes. Take $B = 0_{n \times n}$. This is always true for two diagonal matrices, and may be true for others. The diagonal case is the simplest to cook examples out of.

Comment: Any power of $A$ will commute with any other power of $A$.

Comment: @ClementC. Of course! That makes the most sense, thanks (I can't upvote your answer yet)

Comment: @ClementC. Mind posting your comment as an answer so the question leaves the unanswered question list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comment above: it is possible. Simple examples can be obtained by choosing $A=B$, or $B=0$.